# Avoid increasing size of gridbag layout grid space

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am attempting to keep changing the text of a JLabel by using setText like so:

```
public void nextCard(Player player, PlayingCard card, GameEngine engine) {
    // Displaying the card
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Adding on new card to one drawn.
            playerHand.setText(String.format("%s[%s %s] ", playerHand.getText(),card.getSuit(),card.getValue()));
        }
    });

}
```

The label in question has the following grid bag constraints:

```
            gbc.fill = 0;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
            add(playerHand, gbc);
```

Whenever text is added to the label, it keeps moving everything else around like so: https://gyazo.com/489c9ebf0ca2e5a162ed9066a771787b

Is there a way I could have this text not push the field on the right?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: `The label in question has the following grid bag constraints:` - components don't work in isolation. We need to know the layout of all the components to see how they are related. An "MCVE/SSCCE" as suggested above should be be posted with EVERY question so we don't have to guess what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I could have this text not push the field on the right?

The GridBagLayout works like a grid. If you change the size of one cell in the grid it may affect the size/placement of others around it.

In your case you don't want the component in question to control the width of the column so you can tell the component to take the space of two columns:

```
gbc.gridwidth = 2;
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on the constraints and working examples.